# empty array gets other arrays values in my PHP class

Tags: php, arrays

```
class MyTest{

    public $array1;
    public $array2;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->$array1 = array();
        $this->$array2 = array();
        echo "Hello, I'm constructor<br/>";
        $this->m1();
    }

    function m1(){

        echo 'inside function';

        for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
            $this->$array1[] = $i;
        }

        echo '<br/>Array 1<br/>';
        print_r(array_values($this->$array1));

        echo '<br/>Array 2<br/>';
        print_r(array_values($this->$array2));

    }

}

new MyTest;
```

#### This is the output:

[image]

**Can anybody tell me why this happen :-( ?**

Comment: Since you asked this question, I assume you don't have error reporting enabled in PHP, or you would have seen a bunch of notices that might have helped you figure out what was going on with this. Check into [enabling error reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) for your development environment.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, very helpful information. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put dollar signs on references to your member variables.

```
$this->$array1
$this->$array2
```

Should be

```
$this->array1
$this->array2
```